# Non-greedy mode in re.search() does not match to end of string

Tags: python, regex, non-greedy

I'm trying to parse values of a cookie like this:

```
import re
m = re.search("(.*?)=(.*?); path=(.*?); domain=(.*?)", "name=value1; path=/; domain=my.domain.com")
print (m.group(0))
```

Result I get is like this:

```
name=value1; path=/; domain=
```

My question is: why does it not match at the last non-greedy position? Expected result would be:

```
name=value1; path=/; domain=my.domain.com
```

Of course, I could change to greedy mode or use an end of line character (`$`) but I'd like to understand why it's not working like I expected it to work :)

Comment: What is a "non-greedy position" ?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to call it. Last non-greedy group? I guess it's clear what is meant, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-greedy means it will match as little as it can while still allowing the entire match to succeed.  `*` means "zero or more".  So the least it can match is zero.  So it matches zero and the match succeeds.

The other occurrences of `.*?` in your regex cannot match zero, because then the entire regex will fail to match.

Answer (score 1):

Your last `(.*?)` matches as few characters as possible. To match the rest of the cookie, you must set a lookahead, or match the known characters.

Here is a lookahead solution:

```
(.*?)=(.*?); path=(.*?); domain=(.*?)(?=;\s|$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wV7pQ8/1)

BTW, regex101 is very helpful to get a gist of what is behind the scenes of a regex: go to *regex debugger* and click the `+` on the right, and you'll see what exactly happens when your regex comes to the last `(.*?)`:

[image]

So, that is what I said in the beginning: matching as few as possible. And it matched an empty string after the `=` sign, the rest can be "given away" since this is what [lazy matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) does.

> The standard quantifiers in regular expressions are greedy, meaning
>   they match as much as they can, only giving back as necessary to match
>   the remainder of the regex.
>
> By using a lazy quantifier, the expression tries the minimal match
>   first.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do a great job explaining why your code doesn't work as-is. I'll just point out that honestly you should probably be matching non-space characters greedily, rather than matching all characters non-greedily.

```
re_obj = re.compile(r"""
    (\S*)=(\S*);\s*           # capture unknown key/value pair
    path=(\S*);\s*            # capture path
    domain=(\S*)              # capture domain""", re.X)
```

DEMO

```
>>> result = re_obj.search("name=value1; path=/; domain=my.domain.com")
>>> result.groups()
('name', 'value1', '/', 'my.domain.com')
```

And even more to the point, this seems easier to do with string operations than anything

```
txt = "name=value1; path=/; domain=my.domain.com"
parameters = {key.strip(): value.strip() for parm in txt.split(';') for
              key,value in (parm.strip().split('='),)}
```

Comment: You're right. I'm fixing someone else's code and trying to keep the changes at a minimum though.